# Haskell not recognizing the type

Tags: haskell

I have this custom types

```
data Stack a = Empty | a :<| (Stack a)
             deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
type Value = Int
type ComputerStack = Stack.Stack (Either Address Value)
```

And when i want to do something like this

```
push :: a -> Stack a -> Stack a
push a b = a :<| b

runS :: Value -> ComputerStack -> Seq.Seq Value
runS value stack
  | value == 0  = stack
  | otherwise = runS 0 (Stack.push value stack)
```

I get this

```
    * Couldn't match type `Int' with `Either Address Value'
      Expected type: ComputerStack
        Actual type: Stack.Stack Value
    * In the second argument of `runS', namely
        `(Stack.push value stack)'
      In the expression: runS 0 (Stack.push value stack)
      In an equation for `runS':
          runS value stack
            | value == 0 = stack
            | otherwise = runS 0 (Stack.push value stack)
   |
37 |   | otherwise = runS 0 (Stack.push value stack)
```

My question is, why this is an error since computer stack can be Stack.Stack Value

Comment: runS functions is just an example to showcase the error.

Comment: `stack` is a `Stack.Stack (Either Address Value)` term. The top might be a value (wrapped in `Right`) or it might be an `Address` (whatever that is, wrapped in `Left`).

Comment: Your `value` is an `Int`, how are you supposed to `push` that on a `Stack (Either Address Value)`? It requires the item and the stack to be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `value` is an `Int`, hence `push` can not push that on a `Stack (Either Address Value)`? It requires that the type of the item and the items of the stack are the same.

You can use `Right` to convert it to an `Either a Value` and push that on the stack, so:

```
runS :: Value -> ComputerStack -> ComputerStack
runS value stack
  | value == 0  = stack
  | otherwise = Stack.push (Right value) stack
```

An `Either a b` does not mean that it can be an `a` type or a `b` type. It is a type that has two type constructors `Left` and `Right`. An element of `Either a b` is thus a `Left a` or a `Right b`, but not `a` or `b` directly.